# Xlsx file is corrupted when downloading programmatically (using Python code) from SharePoint : How to solve it?

Tags: python, file, sharepoint, download

I'm using the below Python Code to connect SharePoint and downloading a specific file.
Although the file is being downloaded to the local folder I had set , I can't open the downloaded file.
When trying to Open the file , I'm Getting an error that says that the file corrupted or format not supported

Any Idea how can I solve it ? or use a better solution ?

**** CODE  ****

```
 import sys
 import os
 import xlrd
 import pandas
 from datetime import datetime
 import requests
 from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
 from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
 from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File


 sharePointUrl = 'https://groupdomainname.sharepoint.com'
 username='user@yopmail.com'
 password='passowrd'       
 response=''

 sharepointFilePath="/sites/Investments/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Folders%20For/"
 fileName='File Name.xlsx'

 localPathForDownload="C:\user\download\files\\"


 #1. Authentication : authenticating into your sharepoint site###
 ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(sharePointUrl)
 if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password) : 
   ctx = ClientContext(sharePointUrl, ctx_auth)
   web = ctx.web
   ctx.load(web)
   ctx.execute_query()
   print('Authenticated into sharepoint as: ',web.properties['Title'])
 else:
   print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())


 #2. Downloading : Finding the file and Downlaoding it to a local folder###
 try : 
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, sharepointFilePath + Filename)
    print ("file " + str(fileName) + " was found")
    with open(localPathForDownload+fileName, "wb") as local_file:
          local_file.write(response.content)

 except Exception as e:
    print(str(sys.exc_info()[0])+" : "+str(e.args[0]))
    sys.exit()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC8Hg.png)

Comment: Is it possible to provide the error message in the form of text or image after your code, please?

Comment: @Pawara , I'm using  xlrd to read the file and  This is the error I'm getting :    
  Message=Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'{"error"'

Comment: Same error is happening when i'm trying to open the file directly. I added print screen at the beginning of this thread